# How to click in alphabetical order?

Tags: php, svg, alphabetical

i am new to coding so i would like to ask how can i make the code below, fish able to be click only in alphabetical order which means only fish 'A' can be click first while click on other fish which is not 'A', it can't disappear upon clicking? Is there a way of doing it?

```
<?xml version='1.0' standalone='no'?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">

<svg width='100%' height='100%' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' onload='Init(evt)'>
   <title>Fish Game</title>
   <script type='text/ecmascript'><![CDATA[
      var SVGDocument = null;
      var SVGRoot = null;

      function Init(evt)
      {
         SVGDocument = evt.target.ownerDocument;
         SVGRoot = SVGDocument.documentElement;
      }

      function ToggleOpacity(evt, targetId)
      {
         var newTarget = evt.target;

         if (targetId)
         {
            newTarget = SVGDocument.getElementById(targetId);
         }

         var newValue = newTarget.getAttributeNS(null, 'opacity')

         if ('0' != newValue)
         {
            newValue = '0';
         }
         else
         {
            newValue = '1';
         }

         newTarget.setAttributeNS(null, 'opacity', newValue);

         if (targetId)
         {
            SVGDocument.getElementById(targetId + 'Exception').setAttributeNS(null, 'opacity', '1');
         }
      }
   ]]></script>

 <?php 
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); 
    mysql_select_db("db") or die(mysql_error()); 
    static $data;
    $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM alphabet;") 
    or die(mysql_error()); 

    while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) { 
 ?> 
 <text x="20" y="20"  style="font-family:Times,serif;fill:#B40404;font-size:20px">please find the letter:</text>

//fish body
<g id='<?php print $info['ID']; ?>' onclick='ToggleOpacity(evt, "<?php print $info['ID']; ?>")'>
 <circle cx="<?php print $info['body_cx']; ?>"cy="<?php print $info['body_cy']; ?>" r="<?php print $info['body_r']; ?>" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="<?php print $info['body_fill']; ?>" />

//tail
<path d="<?php print $info['tail']; ?>" fill="<?php print $info['tail_fill']; ?>" stroke="<?php print $info['tail_stroke']; ?>" stroke-width="1" />

//eye
<circle cx="<?php print $info['eye_cx']; ?>" cy="<?php print $info['eye_cy']; ?>" r="<?php print $info['eye_r']; ?>" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="<?php print $info['eye_fill' ];?>" />
<circle cx="<?php print $info['pupil_cx']; ?>" cy="<?php print $info['pupil_cy']; ?>" r="<?php print $info['pupil_r']; ?>" stroke="black" stroke-width="1  " />

//'A'
    <text x="<?php print $info['al_x']; ?>" y="<?php print $info['al_y']; ?>" style="font-family:Times,serif;fill:#B40404;font-size:<?php print $info['size']; ?>"><?php print $info['Alphabet']; ?></text>

    <animateMotion
        from="<?php print $info['from']; ?>" to="<?php print $info['to']; ?>"
        dur="<?php print $info['duration']; ?>"   repeatCount="indefinite" />
   </g>
  <?php   
    }  
 ?>
</svg>
```

Comment: We don't give the answer.  You have to put in effor first, and we'll help you out along the way.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `alphabet` 
ORDER BY  `Alphabet` ASC
```